# Postgresql aggregate related values using triggers

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a database representing a payroll system.
Each *Payroll* is related to several *PayrollRows* (1 to M relationship), and includes a field summarizing its related payrollRows fields.

Simply said, *Payroll* includes a field called "amountEurToPay" which is the sum of the "paybackEur" fields of its related  *PayrollRow* records.

I am trying to create a trigger function that automatically completes the amountEurToPay field when a Payroll is created. (indeed it will be created directly with its payrollRow)

I have done this :

```
-- Generate the trigger function
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER new_payroll_creation  
 AFTER INSERT  
 ON "Payroll"
 FOR EACH ROW  
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE populate_payroll_amountEur();
```

For the function, I tried this, but without any success.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION populate_payroll_amounteur()  
  RETURNS TRIGGER   
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL  
  AS  
$$  
BEGIN  
         UPDATE "Payroll"  
        
         SET "amountEurToPay" =  (   SELECT SUM("paybackEur") 
                                     FROM "PayrollRow"
                                     WHERE "payrollId" = NEW."id")
         WHERE ("id" = NEW."id");  
RETURN NEW;  
END;  
$$
```

For extra information, my schema looks like this

```
model PayrollRow {
  id            Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt     DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime  @updatedAt
  paybackEur    Decimal   @default(0) @db.Decimal(10, 2)
  payroll       Payroll   @relation(fields: [payrollId], references: [id])
  payrollId     Int
}

model Payroll {
  id             Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt      DateTime      @default(now())
  updatedAt      DateTime      @updatedAt
  amountEurToPay Decimal       @default(0) @db.Decimal(10, 2)
  payrollRow     PayrollRow[]
}
```

Could you please provide me some support to achieve that? :)

UPDATE--
It seems that that this works (with a preexisting payroll with id 2) for example, I am a bit confused :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION populate_payroll_amounteur()  
  RETURNS TRIGGER   
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL  
  AS  
$$  
BEGIN  
         UPDATE "Payroll"  
        
         SET "amountEurToPay" =  (   SELECT SUM("paybackEur") 
                                     FROM "PayrollRow"
                                     WHERE "payrollId" = 2)
         WHERE ("id" = NEW."id");  
RETURN NEW;  
END;  
$$
```

---- UPDATE for MiTKo
If you request the schema definition , actually I use prisma.io ORM , which simplified for me the creation of the schema.
Some reverse engineering would give something like this :

```
-- CreateTable
CREATE TABLE "Payroll" (
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "createdAt" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL,
    "amountEurToPay" DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

    CONSTRAINT "Payroll_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
-- CreateTable
CREATE TABLE "PayrollRow" (
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "createdAt" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL,
    "paybackEur" DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "payrollId" INTEGER NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT "PayrollRow_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

    -- AddForeignKey
    ALTER TABLE "PayrollRow" ADD CONSTRAINT "PayrollRow_payrollId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("payrollId") REFERENCES "Payroll"("id") ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: @It512 please provide SQL scripts for your tables

Comment: @MitkoKeckaroski I just updated my main message, thank you for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it's working for update and delete as well)

```
        -- Generate the trigger function
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER new_payroll_creation  
     AFTER INSERT  or UPDATE or delete
     ON "PayrollRow"
     FOR EACH ROW  
     EXECUTE PROCEDURE populate_payroll_amountEur();  
     
    
     
    
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION populate_payroll_amounteur()  
  RETURNS TRIGGER   
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL  
  AS  
$$  
BEGIN  
     UPDATE "Payroll"         
     SET "amountEurToPay" =  
     ( 
      SELECT COALESCE(SUM("paybackEur") ,0)
      FROM "PayrollRow"
      WHERE "payrollId" = COALESCE( NEW."payrollId",OLD."payrollId")
     )
     WHERE ("id" = (COALESCE( NEW."payrollId",OLD."payrollId")));  
RETURN NEW;  
END;  
$$
```

Comment: Thank you for the help ! 
I think you are enabling the trigger when a payrollRow is created. 
This is not a desirable behaviour I think because that would result in too many triggering rights ? Would there be a way to trigger it at Payroll insert ?

Comment: In a 1 to M relationship, you have 1 insert in the Payroll table and more actions on the PayrollRow table (insert, update, delete). So you need to track each change on the PayrollRow table. Please consider inserting a new row in the PayrollRow after a certain time from the initial Payroll creation.    I believe that invoking this trigger isn't an expensive operation but you need to test it :)

Comment: Maybe a point that is not clear is that the Payroll is not supposed to change after its creation. 
So it will or should never be the case that payrollRows will be linked to a previous payroll.

Comment: I think I have a clue why my previous code does not work. 
I use an ORM to create , in what appears to me as a single transaction, a Payroll its related PayrollRow directly. 
Problem comes because I don't know how this translate to sql I think. 
Maybe it first creates the Payroll, then creates the PayrollRows. 
That is why an insert on Payroll gives me 0, because at moment of creation, there is not related payroll rows . 

Would that make sense ?